# How to join the tables for multiple condition?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like below in MS Access

```
Country
India
Boliviano
USA
Phillipines
China
```

Assume there is country field here

```
From  To  ExRate
INR   USD 61.5
BOB   USD 6.9
USD   USD 1
PHI   USD 58.4
YUN   USD 167.5   
EUR   USD 6.7
```

Now i am writing a query to display like below. I want to join the two tables by country column and display the country, exchange rate and the third column would be exchange rate only for specified country(here i have taken as EURO)

```
India       61.5   6.7
USA         1      6.7
India       61.5   6.7
India       61.5   6.7
Phillipines 58.4   6.7
```

Comment: Let me see if i understand. You want to get only the results based on the "TO" column, being in your case EUR. But i don't understand how did you get 6.7 in the third column.

Comment: I am not able to get the third column and that is where i posted this question

Comment: But i can't understand what is the third column?

Comment: basically i have a a country list and what i want is to get the exchange rate for each country so i am joining country list table, country master table(1st table) and currenty table(2nd table) to get first two columns.

Comment: Third columns is just the exchange rate for one master country like in this i have taken Euro as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it is something like this that you want:

```
SELECT c.Country,
  o.ExRate,
  (SELECT ExRate
    FROM exRates
    WHERE `From` = 'EUR'
  ) AS EUR
FROM country c
INNER JOIN exRates o ON c.country = o.country
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24abb/1)</kbd>

The INNER JOIN is not very important here if you have the Country Name in exRates. You could easily query only exRates.